# Remove trailing spaces from string in list, where the list belongs to a dict (value of a dict)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I've a dict object in this format,

```
{'A3' : ['EEE F432 ','EEE F425 ', 'EEE F426 ', 'EEE F416 ', 'EEE F418', 'EEE F427 \n3 0 3'],'A4' : ['ECON F411', 'ME F411', 'ME F412', 'ME F413 ', 'ME F415', 'ME F416', 'ME F417', 'ME F418', 'ME F419', 'ME F420 ', 'ME F432 ']}
```

i need to remove all the white space in the list (the key of the dict) and store it back in the same dictionary. I tried these techniques, but didn't work,

```
#1
for k, v in ref_dict.iteritems():
    map(str.strip, v)

#2
for k, v in ref_dict.iteritems():
    v  = [x.replace(' ', '') for x in v]

#3
for k, v in ref_dict.iteritems():
    for i in v:
        i = i.rstrip()
```

What could have possible gone wrong ?

Comment: `map` doesn't modify `v`, `i.rstrip()` doesn't modify `i`, `v = [...]` doesn't modify `ref_dict[k]`.

Comment: @vaultah made an edit to the third code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work:

```
In [9]: for k in ref_dict:
...:     ref_dict[k] = [re.sub('[\s+]', '', elem) for elem in ref_dict[k]]
...:     

In [10]: ref_dict
Out[10]: 
{'A3': ['EEEF432', 'EEEF425', 'EEEF426', 'EEEF416', 'EEEF418', 'EEEF427303'],
 'A4': ['ECONF411', 'MEF411', 'MEF412', 'MEF413', 'MEF415', 'MEF416', 'MEF417', 'MEF418', 'MEF419', 'MEF420', 'MEF432']}
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 3):

Your attempts don't update the values. You're creating new objects. Instead, try updating the actual entry:

```
for k,v in ref_dict.iteritems():
    ref_dict[k] = [e.strip() for e in v]
```